# Specified child has already a parent

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, android-tabs

this question had been asked here numerous times, however I couldn't find help in any of them. I'm writing an android application and seem to have a problem with creating tabs on the ActionBar. I've been looking for the problem for a couple of hours and can't seem to find the solution, however I think I did find the source. I've even emptied the implementations just to get some results and build upon them but alas I didn't find anything.

this is the creating of the tab fragment and insertion to the actionbar

```
    // put ActionBar to nav. mode
    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    // init "YES" tab
    Fragment yesTabFragment = Fragment.instantiate(this, YesTabFragment.class.getName());
    FlowTabListener yesTabListener = new FlowTabListener(yesTabFragment);
    ActionBar.Tab yesTab = actionBar.newTab().setText("YES").setTabListener(yesTabListener);
    actionBar.addTab(yesTab);
```

this is the onCreateView method of the class

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    _fragmentView =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.yes_fragment, container);    
}
```

and this is the fragment XML layout

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:orientation="vertical" >

    </LinearLayout>
```

as you can see, the implementations are empty, and i do not instantiate this fragment before this time (and not after) however I get this error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(2995): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(2995): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{activities.MainActivity}:    
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
```

I think it has something to do with the addition of the tab to the action bar since when I comment out the `actionBar.addTab()` the application does run (without the tabs obviously)

I would really like for a hint on how to sort this out.

Thanks a head guys

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The second parameter of `inflate()` is the default parent:

```
_fragmentView =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.yes_fragment, container);
```

Change this line to:

```
_fragmentView =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.yes_fragment, null);
```

Comment: Thanks! it worked like a charm. could you please explain what did I do wrong (since I couldn't find it I guess I do not understand it). I would really appreciate that. Thanks again!!!

Comment: Sure, each view can only have one parent. In your code, `inflate()` sets parent of `_fragmentView` to `container` by default. When you try to add it as a tab, the action bar needs to define itself as the (only) parent. (Rather than automatically attempt to "abduct" this child, it simply throws the exception.)  By using `null` instead of `container` you are creating `_fragmentView` without a parent, later the action bar will set itself as the parent of `_fragmentView`. Does that help?

Comment: I see that makes sense now... thank you so much, I wish I could give you rating, but I'm still a noob here :)

Comment: No trouble. Please click the checkmark, this will give me a small rating and indicate the question is solved.

Comment: I am facing same problem for fragments even i am using like this also.View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_chats, null ); http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15194618/android-the-specified-child-already-has-a-parent-for-fragments-oncreateview#comment21409705_15194618