# Android "The specified child already has a parent." for Fragments onCreateView()?

Tags: android, compiler-errors, android-listfragment

I'm using SherlockFragments in my Android application using the compatibility package. Getting this error for `fragments`. `FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.` I am adding these fragments as tabs in actionbar sherlock. After run the app successfully when i am switching tabs first time it's working fine, in second time it's giving the above error in onCreateView()..

this is the code in onCreate()

```
private static final String AD_UNIT_STANDARD_BANNER = "/6253334/dfp_example_ad/banner";
private DfpAdView adView;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 

    adView = new DfpAdView(getActivity(), AdSize.BANNER, AD_UNIT_STANDARD_BANNER);  
    adView.setAdListener(this);
}
```

this is the code i am using in fragment onCreateView().

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {     
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_chats, container, false);         
    listview = (ListView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.list); 
    RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.chats_inner_layout);

    adView.setId(111);
    adView.loadAd(new AdRequest());        
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams add_lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    add_lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, adView.getId());   
    listview.setLayoutParams(add_lp);

    //**** this is the line causing for error****/////
    layout.addView(adView);         
    return view;         
}
```

this is the xml code for above fragment

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:id="@+id/chats_main_layout"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:background="@color/app_lite_theme"
   android:orientation="vertical" >

   <RelativeLayout
      android:id="@+id/chats_inner_layout"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:orientation="vertical" >

      <ListView
          android:id="@android:id/list"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
          android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
          android:scrollbars="none" />

   </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

this same code i am using for fragments that is working fine without any problems. i am facing problem with fragments only. What is the problem here ? anybody tell
 me solution for this.

Comment: Where do you instantiate `adView` ? as it is posted this code should result in NullPointerException.

Comment: @FoamyGuy i was initiated in onCreate(), edited my Question with some more details look at that..

Comment: where is javadoc for `DfpAdView` class? perhaps the constructor is adding it to a parent layout.

Comment: javadoc for DfpAdView class is a jar file, i am importing them like this import com.google.ads.doubleclick.DfpAdView; and i am adding adView to the inner layout not for main layout.

Comment: It is advised to have adView to be inside a `LinearLayout` than a `RelativeLayout`

Comment: @Pallavi this error not related what layout i am using here.

Comment: @RajaReddyPolamReddy true.. declare adview in `onCreateView` itself, so that new instances are created each time you call new fragment.

Answer (score 0):

I think somethings wrong in this  part

```
  listview.setLayoutParams(add_lp);
```

it should be

```
 addView.setLayoutParams(add_lp);
```

Comment: this will not cause the error same code is working for activities..i am facing problems in fragments only..